# Set Global Variable onclick in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to set a global variable in Jquery so that when I click on a list item, the id of the clicked list item becomes the value of the variable.
I have the below code which is also in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LbZe6/).

However the way I have it: At the moment when you click the list item,the value correctly gets put in the console.log.However afterthat when I click in the demo div,the variable is reset and is undefined.

How do I get the value of id when I click on demo,to be the value of id when I click on the list item?

eg :

**when I click on aaa,the value when I click on the demo box should be id-1**

**when I click on bbb,the value when I click on the demo box should be id-2**

```
    <div id="demo"></div>
    <ul>
        <li id="id-1">aaa</li>
        <li id="id-2">bbb</li>
    </ul>

    <script>
    var id;
    jQuery(document).on("click", "li", function (event) {
            var id =jQuery(this).attr('id') || '';
            console.log(id);
        $( "#demo" ).show();
        });

    $(function() {
    $("#demo").click(function(e) {
    console.log(id);
    });
    });

    </script>

    <style>
    #demo {
        border: 1px solid; 
        display:none;
        height: 100px; 
        width: 100px;
    }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  var id;
  jQuery(document).on("click", "li", function (event) {
      //should not not var here, using var here will declare the variable id as a local variable in the handler function scope
      id = jQuery(this).attr('id') || '';
      console.log(id);
      $("#demo").show();
  });

  $(function () {
      $("#demo").click(function (e) {
          console.log(id);
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

You are again declared  `id` inside the loop.

```
 var id;
    jQuery(document).on("click", "li", function (event) {
            id =jQuery(this).attr('id') || '';
            console.log(id);
        $( "#demo" ).show();
        });
```

change

```
var id =jQuery(this).attr('id') || ''; to 

id =jQuery(this).attr('id') || ''; inside the loop.
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you  re declare `var id`

```
var id;  // GLOBAL
jQuery(document).on("click", "li", function (event) {
        var id =jQuery(this).attr('id') || ''; // LOCAL TO THIS BLOCK
```

so just use Global variable ,

```
var id;  // GLOBAL
jQuery(document).on("click", "li", function (event) {
id =jQuery(this).attr('id') || ''; // Use GLOBAL id here
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/devmgs/LbZe6/1/

dont use var inside as it will make it local variable

```
var id;
jQuery(document).on("click", "li", function (event) {
        id =jQuery(this).attr('id') || '';
        console.log(id);
    $( "#demo" ).show();
    });

$(function() {
$("#demo").click(function(e) {
console.log(id);
});
});
```