# Top level mouse event handler

Tags: javascript, canvas, mouse

Hm. Maybe Is that I can't figure out the correct search keywords, since I'm new in some areas of javascript.

I am making a two.js based interactive game that comprises dragging stuff around. I need to detect when a mouse is released regardless the elements that are (or aren't) over the canvas. The elements (which are SVG canvas elements) capture the mouse events and prevent the canvas mouse event detection.

Mouse events:

```
$("#canvas").on("mousemove", function(e){
    //do stuff
}).on("mousedown",function(){
    //do stuff
}).on("mouseup",function(){
    //do stuff
})
```

So, I can either address a event handler to an object, which will happen only within that object, or address it to the canvas, which will only happen when there is no object over. Appending to both will be unelegant, and will need a major re estructuration in the code that is huge (and I admit, messy);

[Example elements that steal the mouse events in the inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6PsQ.png)

I hope not to be re-asking. I have looked up and tried for some hours. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Don't lose focus when clicking another element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215211/dont-lose-focus-when-clicking-another-element)

Comment: so there is not any sort of global mouse event? only object listeners? that is awful!

Comment: Although you can use `$(document).bind("click", function() {});` to actually _bind_ a click event to the whole document, to tackle the issue you presented, perhaps taking a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19021096/4814251) answer would help, sorry for the 'duplicate' flag without explaining further...

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So I tried an approach trying to think more javascript wise. Mainly I come from the other OOP school of thought; which is why is hard to unlock my understanding of prototypical objects.

I made a global function named pointer, and other named draggable, which goes in the prototype of each object to be dragged. On this function and over any object over which things could be dragged (the canvas), I attached the functions onRelease and release. When the mouse button is released, it runs its release function, which triggers a pointer.release(). The pointer will have an array of any object being dragged, so when it receives the release, it will trigger the onRelease of each dragged element, passing the object under the mouse. So the object being dragged, at the end receives the event handling object (the one upon which mouse was released).

I hope this method doesn't produce any face-palm. If so, I'd like to learn how it was better.

```
var pointer={
 pos:{x:0,y:0},
 dragging:false,
 //who will be the object that detected the mouse released. see below
 mouseUp:function(who){
    for(drg in this.dragging){
           //look if the -being-dragged- object does have the function
            if(typeof(this.dragging.onRelease)=="function")
                this.dragging.onRelease(who);
        this.dragging=false;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the draggable class. The last part is the only concerning one, the rest is for context purpose:

```
function Draggable(){
this.main=this;
if(!this.pos)
    this.pos={x:0,y:0};
this.dragging=false;
this.hover=false;
this.sprite=false;
this.move=function(pos){
    this.sprite.translation.x=pos.x;
    this.sprite.translation.y=pos.y;
    this.pos=pos;
    this.moving();
}
this.moving=function(){}
this.release=function(){
    pointer.mouseUp(this);
}
this.init=function(){
    //fallback sprite is a circle
    if(!this.sprite)
        this.sprite=two.makeCircle(0,0,this.rad);

    this.move(this.pos);
    two.update();
    this.elem=$(domElem(this.sprite));
    //attach a this to the dom element to make back-scope
    this.elem[0].main=this;
    //append jquery functions to this object's dom sprite
    //pendiente: this may need to go in the pointer object, isn't it?
    this.elem.on("mouseenter",function(){
        this.main.sprite.fill="rgba(127,127,255,0.7)";
        this.main.hover=true;
    }).on("mouseleave",function(){
        this.main.sprite.fill="rgba(127,127,255,0.3)";
        this.main.hover=false;
        //avoid pieces stuck to mouse. should this be?
        /*this.main.dragging=false;
        this.main.release();
        pointer.dragging=false;*/
    }).on("mousedown",function(){
        this.main.dragging=this.main.hover;
        pointer.dragging=this.main;
    }).on("mouseup",function(){
        //the important part is here: it triggers an pointer.mouseUp
        this.main.dragging=false;
        this.main.release();
        pointer.mouseUp(this);
    });
}
```

};

And so the node which will be prototype-blended with the draggable

```
function Node(ind){
 //just to make more console-friendly
 this.name="node"+ind;
 this.pos=a;
 this.ind=ind;
 this.par=par;
 this.broc;
 this.sprite=two.makeCircle(0,0,brocSize*1.2);
 this.sprite.addTo(layer[2]);
 this.$elem=$(domElem(this.sprite));
 main=this;
 //these are triggered by their draggable bit
 //who, is the subject over which mouse was released
 this.onRelease=function(who){
    //if(typeof(who)=="Broc")
    console.log(who);
    this.move(this.broc.pos);
    console.log("this:");
    console.log(this);
  }

  //pendant: make the abspos function once an unpack
  this.son=false;
  this.active=false;
};
```

This implements a bit of jQuery, which may later be replaced by plain javascript, for prototype and learn purposes I feel more comfortable with jQuery.